# jquery (windows).height increase every time I resize the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window-resize

I want to resize a div on resize of the window to make it fill the entire browser window...
I searched a lot on internet finding a solution, but everything I tried cause the same problem...
at first load of the page it works well, but when I try to resize the window the value of bodyheight keeps increasing...

this is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  body_sizer();
  $(window).resize(body_sizer);
});
function body_sizer() {
  var bodyheight = $(window).height();
  $("#contenitore_full").css('height', bodyheight);
}
```

EDIT

OK!!! my fault as i thought :)
problem was caused by a wrong way to call jquery in wordpress.
i'm sorry for let you loose time
thanks a lot everyone
ale

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/2R8um/

Comment: yes it seems, but it doesn't in my template... maybe some conflict, but i don't figure out what's the problem...

Comment: I have the identical problem but the height is smaller each time. Haven't found it out yet.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need javascript to achieve what you want. All you need is CSS.
Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2R8um/1/)

**CSS**

```
body, html { margin:0; height:100% }
#contenitore_full { border:1px solid #FF0000; width:25%; height:99%; display:block; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="contenitore_full"></div>
```

The thing is in order for `height` to work, the parent's height also needs to be defined. That's why the `height` of the `body` and `html` tags also have a `height` of `100%`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your 'body_sizer' function might not be firing. Add your parens () to the end of it or either create an handler function inside .resize()

```
$(window).resize(function() {
      var bodyheight = $(window).height();
      $("#contenitore_full").css('height', bodyheight);
});
```

Comment: tried your code, but do not resolve the problem.. i think there will be some conflict, but don't know how to solve it... thanks a lot anyway

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I recommend using javascript instead of jQuery.

```
  const width = window.innerWidth;
  const height = window.innerHeight;
```